# RxJava: OnErrorFailedException. Identifying the correct cause

Tags: java, functional-programming, rx-java, reactive-programming

Being inspired by T.Nurkiewicz's "Reactive Programming with RxJava" I tried to apply it in a project that I am working on and here's the issue that I am facing.

I have a Rest end point that takes an input stream and a username and either returns a link for the updated username or returns a Bad Request error. Here's how I tried to implement this using RxJava:

```
    @PUT
    @Path("{username}")
    public Response updateCredential(@PathParam("username") final String username, InputStream stream) {
        CredentialCandidate candidate = new CredentialCandidate();
        Observable.just(repository.getByUsername(username))
                .subscribe(
                    credential -> {
                            serializeCandidate(candidate, stream);
                            try {
                                repository.updateCredential(build(credential, candidate));
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                String msg = "Failed to update credential +\""+username+"\": "+e.getMessage();
                                throw new BadRequestException(msg, Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).build());
                            }
                        },
                        ex -> {
                            String msg = "Couldn't update credential \""+username+"\""
                            + ". A credential with such username doesn't exist: " + ex.getMessage();
                            logger.error(msg);
                            throw new BadRequestException(msg, Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).build());
                });//if the Observable completes without exceptions we have a success case
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("path", "credential/" + username);
        return Response.ok(getJsonRepr("link", uriGenerator.apply(appsUriBuilder, map).toASCIIString())).build();
}
```

My issue is at the line 11 (the catch clause of the `onNext` method). This is the log output that quickly will demonstrate what happens:

```
19:23:50.472 [http-listener(4)] ERROR com.vgorcinschi.rimmanew.rest.services.CredentialResourceService             - Couldn't update credential "admin". A credential with such username doesn't exist: Failed to update credential +"admin": Password too weak!
```

So the exception thrown in the `onNext` method goes to the upstream and ends-up in the `onError` method! Apparently [this works as designed](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/3679), but I am confused as to how I could return the correct reason of the Bad Request Error. After all in my test case a credential with the user was found by the repository, the correct error was that the suggested password was too weak. This is the helper method that generated the error:

```
private Credential build(Credential credential, CredentialCandidate candidate) {
         if(!isOkPsswd.test(candidate.getPassword())){
            throw new BadRequestException("Password too weak!", Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).build());
        }
...
}
```

I am still fairly new to Reactive Programming so I realise I may be missing something that is obvious. Skimming through the book didn't get me to an answer, so I would appreciate any help.

Just in case, this is the full stack trace:

```
updateCredentialTest(com.vgorcinschi.rimmanew.services.CredentialResourceServiceTest)  Time elapsed: 0.798 sec  <<< ERROR!
rx.exceptions.OnErrorFailedException: Error occurred when trying to propagate error to Observer.onError
    at com.vgorcinschi.rimmanew.rest.services.CredentialResourceService.lambda$updateCredential$9(CredentialResourceService.java:245)
    at rx.internal.util.ActionSubscriber.onNext(ActionSubscriber.java:39)
    at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onNext(SafeSubscriber.java:134)
    at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$WeakSingleProducer.request(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:276)
    at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:209)
    at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:205)
    at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$JustOnSubscribe.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:138)
    at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$JustOnSubscribe.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:129)
    at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10238)
    at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10205)
    at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10045)
    at com.vgorcinschi.rimmanew.rest.services.CredentialResourceService.updateCredential(CredentialResourceService.java:238)
    at com.vgorcinschi.rimmanew.services.CredentialResourceServiceTest.updateCredentialTest(CredentialResourceServiceTest.java:140)
```

Answer (score 3):

It's seems you didn't grasp Reactive programming principles right.

First thing is that `Observable` are asynchronous by their API, while you are trying to enforce it to be synchronous API, by trying to return the `Response`  value directly from the method, instead of returning `Observable<Response>` that emits this `Response` value over time by its `onNext()` notification.
That's why you are struggling with the exception, each notification lambda method (`onNext`/`onError`) is encapsulated by the `Observable` mechanism, in order to create a proper stream that obey some rules (the [Observable contract](http://reactivex.io/documentation/contract.html)), some of those expected behaviors are that errors should be redirect to the `onError()` method, which is the exception catch method, you shouldn't throw there, and throwing there will be considered as fatal error and will swallowed by throwing `OnErrorFailedException`.

Ideally it will be something like this:

```
public Observable<Response> updateCredential(@PathParam("username") final String username,
                                             InputStream stream) {
    rerurn Observable.fromCallable(() -> {
        CredentialCandidate candidate = new CredentialCandidate();
        Credential credential = repository.getByUsername(username);
        serializeCandidate(candidate, stream);
        repository.updateCredential(build(credential, candidate));
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("path", "credential/" + username);
        return Response.ok(getJsonRepr("link", uriGenerator.apply(appsUriBuilder, map).toASCIIString())).build();
    })
            .onErrorReturn(throwable -> {
                String msg = "Failed to update credential +\"" + username + "\": " + e.getMessage();
                throw new BadRequestException(msg, Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).build());
            });
}
```

use `fromCallable` in order to make the request happen when subscribing (while `Observable.just(repository.getByUsername(username))` will act synchronously when the Observable is constructs ), the success path is withing the callable itself, while if any error occurred, you will transform it to your custom exception using `onErrorReturn` operator.

with his approach you will return `Observable` object that will act when you will subscribe to it, you will get all the benefits of `Observable` and Reactive approach such being able to compose it with some other operations, being able to specify from outside whether it will act synchronously (current thread) or async on some other thread (using `Scheduler`) .

For more detailed explanation regarding reactive programming I suggest to start from this great [tutorial](https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754) from André Staltz.